# How to stop python script that launches raspivid

Tags: python, camera

I have the following line of code in a `.py` file

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -hf -w 640 -h 360 -fps 25 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554}' :demux=h264
```

When I execute videoscript.py the line above starts a stream from my `RPi 2 B running Raspbian 4.4` I can then view the stream via VLC on a laptop on my network.

**Question:**
How do I stop the stream? Do I need to create a new .py file that quits?

Comment: It appears that the script runs in the foreground so you can probably kill it with ctrl-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a "ps aux", find the process id and do "kill -9 pid" where pid is the process number you wanna kill.
If the process is active, just hit ctrl-c to abort or ctrl-z to put to sleep.